# How to extend the DBContext (of EF6.0) with custom security

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm actually trying to extend the EF with a custom user security.

Actually, my logic checks for permissions in its own, seperate function that does not have a real context to the EF. But it would be great if i could attach my logic directly to the DBContext, that way every linq-Query will be checked.

I've found the "IDbCommandInterceptor" interface, but this is called too late for me, because i'm checking for types.

Code for the permission check:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Checks if the current user have the given rights for the given permission 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permittedType"></param>
    /// <param name="requiredPerm"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private CheckResult CheckPermissionFor(Type permittedType, Permissions requiredPerm)
    {
        CheckResult Result = new CheckResult();
        String TypeName = permittedType.Name;
        EntityObjectInfo ObjInfo = (from info in BaseData.EntityInfos where info.Name == TypeName select info).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ObjInfo != null)
        {
            if (ObjInfo.IsSecurityEnabled)
            {
                //Getting all permissions from assinged userpermissions with the right objectname
                IEnumerable<EntityPermission> ObjPerms = Session.AssingedEntityPermissions.Where(f => f.PermittedObject.Name == TypeName);

                if (ObjPerms.Any())
                {
                    //Check if any permission have readonly rights or higher to load the obj
                    if (ObjPerms.Max(f => f.Permission) < requiredPerm)
                        Result.Messages.AddMessage("No permission to " + requiredPerm + " for " + TypeName, MessageType.Error);
                }
                else
                    Result.Messages.AddMessage("No permission for " + TypeName, MessageType.Error);
            }
        }
        else
            Result.Messages.AddMessage("Missing objectinfo for " + TypeName, MessageType.Error);        

        return Result;
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, one approach can be

1. Derive your own context from DbContext
2. Use some kind of LoggedOnUser in constructor of your context. This entity can store permissions.
3. Implement permissions check in getter of entites like this

   ```
   public DbSet<ClientAddress> ClientAddresses
   { 
       get; //TODO add getting logic with checking permissions
       set;
   }
   ```
4. Use Attributes on partial classes (context entites), co you can describe required permission
5. Use T4 generation item in your model. There you can modify output .cs file, so with new entity in your database you don't need to rewrite everything and goal 3 can be autogenerated.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought to the getter -.-! I think this will help me.